# load `<select>` drop down default value using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

i need to load default value for my drop downs.

first drop down

```
<select class="form-control pz" ng-model="newuser.title">
    <option ng-repeat="x in titles" value="{{x}}">{{x}}</option>
</select>
```

data for first drop down

```
$scope.titles = ["MR","MRS","MS"];
```

I need to load "MR" as a default value in my first drop down.

second drop down with data.

```
<select class="form-control"  ng-model="newuser.assessmentyear" required
        ng-option="x in assessmentyears">
    <option selected>--Select Year--</option>
    <option ng-repeat="x in assessmentyears" value="{{x}}">{{x}}</option>
</select>
```

I need to load "--Select Year--" as a default value.

can you help

Comment: Did you try to set newuser.title = 'MR' from model?

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, you need to set ng-model value with the value of the first option:

```
$scope.newuser = {};
$scope.newuser.title = "MR";
```

For the second dropdown add `value=""` to set default option as selected:

```
<option value="">--Select Year--</option>
```

Note also that this is not needed:

```
ng-option="x in assessmentyears"
```

as you are adding options with `ng-repeat`.

You can see documentation and similar examples here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select